# How can a payment amount be rounded down to the second decimal place

Tags: c#

The payment amounts entered at a cash register must always be rounded down to the second decimal place, as 5 cent coins cannot be processed.

An example: `1.55` should result in `1.50` and not `1.60`, so the second decimal place should always be 0, while the first one must not be rounded up. I've tested everything possible, but can't find a sensible solution. Does anyone know a simple trick?

```
  decimal result;
  if (decimal.TryParse(txtZahlungsbetrag.Text, out result))
  {
       //txtZahlungsbetrag.Text = Math.Round(result, 1).ToString("0.0#");
       //txtZahlungsbetrag.Text = string.Format("{0:0.0}" + "0", result); 
       txtZahlungsbetrag.Text = string.Format("{0:n1}" + "0", result);
  }
```

Comment: Multiply by 10, truncate, divide by 10?

Comment: `var roundedVal = Math.ceil(result*20)/20;`

Comment: What's a harvest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Math.Round(result - 0.05m, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

By subtracting 0.05 we ensure that we round down, and by using `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` we ensure that for example, `1.60 - 0.05`, or `1.55` is rounded back up to `1.60`.